# Initializing object with closure as only parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I have an auto-generated swift class from one of my Obj-C pods that looks like this:

```
typealias BlockDomainMapperMappingBlock = (AnyObject!) -> AnyObject!

class BlockDomainMapper : DomainMapper {

    var mappingBlock: BlockDomainMapperMappingBlock! { get }

    /*not inherited*/ init!(block: BlockDomainMapperMappingBlock!)
}
```

When trying to initialize the object like so:

```
let domainMapper = BlockDomainMapper { (objectToMap : AnyObject!) -> AnyObject! in
   return LoginCredentials(token: objectToMap)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'BlockDomainMapper' that accepts
>   an argument list of type '((AnyObject!) -> AnyObject!)'

This baffles me, as I am using the auto-complete in X-Code to generate the most of the code (except: (objectToMap : AnyObject!), which starts out as an AnyObject! placeholder.)

EDIT: This is the objective-C code that generates the swift class:

```
typedef id (^BlockDomainMapperMappingBlock)(id dataToMap);

@interface BlockDomainMapper : GLTDomainMapper

@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) BlockDomainMapperMappingBlock mappingBlock;

+ (BlockDomainMapper *)mapperWithBlock:(BlockDomainMapperMappingBlock)block;

@end
```

EDIT 2: Wow! After looking at the Obj-c code again, I think it either botched the mapperWithBlock conversion, or I'm using the wrong syntax to invoke that kind of class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know what I did wrong. Here's some code that works.

```
let domainMapper = BlockDomainMapper { (objectToMap : AnyObject!) -> AnyObject! in
   return LoginCredentials(token: objectToMap as! String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`let domainMapper = BlockDomainMapper() { (objectToMap : AnyObject!)`

(i.e. include `()` after BlockDomainManager())

Comment: Nah, doesn't work. Also, remember that this snippet was generated by X-Code. It should know how to auto-complete blocks...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the Objective-C code you're starting from has a "class factory" convenience method `mapperWithBlock:` for creating `BlockDomainMapper` objects. That's not the same thing as an initializer. It uses an initializer.

Your initializer is the equivalent of an Objective-C call `+initWithBlock:`

If you want to call your initializer you need to add a parameter label:

```
let domainMapper = BlockDomainMapper(block: 
  { (objectToMap : AnyObject!) -> AnyObject! in
    return LoginCredentials(token: objectToMap)
  }
```

That *should* work.

(I'm still learning the finer points of Swift, so I'm not 100% positive, but I think that's what you need to do.)

Comment: You know, I tried this as well. No luck. It keeps complaining about the same thing. I wonder if it has something to do with the initializer in obj-c being private, and not named correctly initWithMappingBlock instead of initWithBlock

Comment: "I wonder if it has something to do with the initializer in obj-c being private, and not named correctly initWithMappingBlock instead of initWithBlock". Yes, that is almost certainly the problem. The class doesn't provide a public initializer, just the "class factory" method. You have the method `init!(block: BlockDomainMapperMappingBlock!)`, which should allow you to call `BlockDomainMapper(block:)`.

Comment: Ok, maybe it was the Swift interop thing that didn't re-compile the obj-c code after me fixing it. Will check again.

Comment: This is so weird. As soon as I change the block types from id to NSString * it can find them...

Comment: It just doesn't seem to work with the id -> AnyObject! conversion.